# How do I keep the geometry of instances in place when moving the origin?

Tags: instances, origin

For my job, I'm often sent converted CAD objects that need to have their origins fixed before I animate them. I need the geometry to stay in place and the origin to move. In the previous version I had installed (3.0.1) as long as I had all instanced objects selected, the geometry of all of them would stay put and the origin would move. In 3.3.1, however, that is no longer the case.

In the example below, moving each instance would not be much of a problem. However, I sometimes get CAD files with dozens or even hundreds of instances of a single piece of hardware.

Is there another way of doing what I need, or should I stick with 3.0.1?
[image: Before and after screenshots of instanced geometry shifting when the origin is moved.]

Comment: Hi Robyn, welcome to Blender SE. The problem (this is just my personal opinion) with your question is, that it is not clear to me. How did you create your instances? with geometry nodes? something else? how do you move your objects? do you know of these options here [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eitPi.png ? there you can choose what you wanna move...

Comment: @Chris, The objects in question are imported as instances. They share the same Mesh Data. I tried checking different combinations of that "Affect Only" list and the result is the same. I am trying to edit the origin via Object -> Set Origin -> to 3D Cursor. If there is a better way to do this, I would love to know.

Comment: @Chris Nevermind, I figured out how to snap the origins where I need them. This... should work well enough.